Is it possible to nest named capturing groups in a Regular expression to process the same string twice?
I'm trying to build a regular expression for a Grok pattern. The goal is: giving a sequence of digits, I need to assign the first eleven numbers to a named capturing group, and then digits from positions 3 to 10 to a different named capturing group, starting from the beginning. For example, if the string is:
2012345678900112255

the named groups should be:
gr1: 20123456789 (first 11)
gr2: 12345678 (3 to 10)

The expression I've tried is
(?<gr1>\d{11})^\d{2}(?<gr2>\d{8})

but I think that is an incorrect use of the ^, since it doesn't start over at the beginning of the string.
I've tested this in https://regexr.com/ and I'm not getting an error, but not a match either.
This is to build a custom classifier in AWS Glue, so I don't know the language.

Try (?<gr1>\d\d(?<gr2>\d{8})\d), which has your two captures actually nested.  Your approach would only work if one of the captures was in a lookahead or lookbehind, so that it could start over at the beginning of the string.

How about (?:\d{2}(\d{9})) or ^(?:\d{2}(\d{9})) or ^(\d{2}(\d{9}))?

Thank you @jasonharper, your regex works just fine.
